# How to use outer query column inside inner query column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run postgresql query below

```
SELECT *
FROM user_follow uf
       INNER JOIN (SELECT uplr.post, COUNT(*)
                   FROM user_post_like_relation uplr
                   WHERE uplr.category = 'like' AND uf.recently_viewed < uplr.created_at . //CANNOT reference uf
                     AND clicked = true
                   GROUP BY uplr.post) uplr
    ON uplr.post = uf.post
INNER JOIN post p ON uf.post = p.id
```

Unfortunately I am not able to reference `uf` inside the INNER JOIN query but it is essential that I join and also reference the recently_viewed column in side the JOIN query. Is there a way of overcoming this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is sufficient in your case to just `JOIN` to the table and `GROUP` the results to perform `COUNT`.

```
SELECT uf.post, p.id, count(*)
FROM user_follow uf
JOIN post p ON uf.post = p.id
JOIN user_post_like_relation uplr ON uplr.post = uf.post
WHERE uplr.category = 'like'
  AND clicked = 'true'
  AND uf.recently_viewed < uplr.created_at
GROUP BY uf.post, p.id
```

Play with `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns to get ones which you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `INNER JOIN LATERAL` if you want to reference columns from previous `FROM` list entries.

This is available from PostgreSQL 9.3 on.